# how to show arrow only when hover slideshow html css javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to show arrows only when the mouse hover on the image.

Is there any way this can be done in CSS, html or Javascript.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
<html>
<style>
.prev {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 34%;
    left: 0;
}

.prev:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.next {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 34%;
    right: 0;
}

.next:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}

</style>

<body>
<div class="outerBox">

                <img src="SliderLeftArrow.svg" alt ="Prev" class = "prev" /> 

                <img src="SliderRightArrow.svg" alt ="Next" class = "next"/>

                <img src="image1.jpg" class="imageBox" id="image_slider" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Jaromanda X, your answer solved the problem. Here i used your answer:

Comment: <div class="outerBox">
       <img onclick="prev()" alt ="Prev" src="SliderLeftArrow.svg" class = "prev" style="left: 0;"/> 
     <img onclick="next()" alt ="Next" src="SliderRightArrow.svg" class = "next"/ style="right: 0;">
                <img src="image1.jpg" class="imageBox" id="image_slider" />
               
 </div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want the arrows to appear when hovering over the image - one way is to have the css as follows (I've dummied up image and arrows as pure text, but the principal remains the same)

```css
.prev,
.next 
{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 800ms;
}

.outerBox:hover .prev,
.outerBox:hover .next
{
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerBox">

                <span class="prev">&lt;&lt;&lt;</span>
                <span>I am an image</span>
                <span class="next">&gt;&gt;&gt;</span>
</div>
```

I also added a transition to the opacity, because I like transitions :p

Comment: This is a well explained alternative to my answer +1 upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code and your problem should be fixed.

```
.prev, .next {
     visibility: hidden;
}
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
     visibility: hidden;
}
```

Or this code.

```
.prev, .next {
     color: /*whatever the background color is i.e. white*/;
}
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
     color: /*something contrasting from your background color i.e. black*/;
}
```

Comment: *There is a trick in css with hover* - you mean like `.prev:hover` and `.next:hover` in the **question** - I think you've misunderstood what the question actually is